# Laravel group by issues with an inline select statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The SQL below works fine. It's taking this and implementing it in Laravel, where the issue is.
The **sqlfiddle** can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c6727/1).

```
SELECT provider_id
     , o.shortName
     , count(b.site_id) as sites
     , ( select b.depositFee 
              + ( select sum(depositFee) 
                    from backhaul 
                   where backhaul.parent_id=b.id
                ) 
       ) as entranceFee
     , ( select b.rightOfWayCharges 
              + ( select sum(rightOfWayCharges) 
                    from backhaul 
                   where backhaul.parent_id = b.id
                )
       ) as rowFee
    FROM backhaul AS b
    JOIN organisation AS o  
      ON (b.provider_id = o.id)
   WHERE isnull(b.parent_id)
   GROUP 
      BY provider_id
       , entranceFee
       , rowFee
```

The table is recursive. Which gives me these results below:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
provider_id | sshortName | sites | entranceFee | rowFee
--------------------------------------------------------
802 | TM | 1 | 12500.00 | 7500.00  
803 | TIME | 1 | 7500.00 | 0.00
```

**The issue is Laravel can't seem to recognise the '`entranceFee`' or '`rowFee`' columns on the group by statement.**

My Lararvel 5.7 implementation looks like this:

```
$sql = DB::raw("provider_id, o.shortName, count(b.site_id) as sites," .
"(select b.depositFee + (select sum(depositFee) from backhaul where backhaul.parent_id=b.id)) as entranceFee," .
"(select b.rightOfWayCharges + (select sum(rightOfWayCharges) from backhaul where backhaul.parent_id=b.id)) as rowFee") ;

$data = DB::table("backhaul as b")->select($sql)
   ->join("organisation as o", "b.provider_id", "=", "o.id")
   ->whereNull("b.parent_id")
   ->groupBy("b.provider_id", DB::raw("entranceFee"), DB::raw("rowFee"))
   ->paginate() ;
```

I'm getting the usual MySQL group by error about SELECT #4 missing from the GROUP BY statement.

I've tried adding as an array `groupBy(["provider_id", DB::raw("entranceFee"), DB::raw("rowFee")])` but still it barfs. If I add the inline SQL selects as well, it barfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/problem-the-sub-selects-with-sum-and-group-by-statement?page=1#reply=531722) by Tray2:

The solution below is confirmed to work:

```
$data = DB::select('SELECT provider_id
     , o.shortName
     , count(b.site_id) as sites
     , ( select b.depositFee 
              + ( select sum(depositFee) 
                    from backhaul 
                   where backhaul.parent_id=b.id
                ) 
       ) as entranceFee
     , ( select b.rightOfWayCharges 
              + ( select sum(rightOfWayCharges) 
                    from backhaul 
                   where backhaul.parent_id = b.id
                )
       ) as rowFee
    FROM backhaul AS b
    JOIN organisation AS o  
      ON (b.provider_id = o.id)
   WHERE isnull(b.parent_id)
   GROUP 
      BY provider_id
       , entranceFee
       , rowFee');
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel is likely wrapping those in backticks which will cause MySQL to believe they are actual columns in a table somewhere.  Try wrapping those in `DB::raw` as well.

```
$data = DB::table("backhaul as b")->select($sql)
    ->join("organisation as o", "b.provider_id", "=", "o.id")
    ->whereNull("b.parent_id")
    ->groupBy([
        "b.provider_id",
        \DB::raw('entranceFee'),
        \DB::raw('rowFee'),
    ])
    ->paginate() ;
```

Comment: Thanks user1669496, I tried that. However, I'm now getting: `Unknown column 'entranceFee' in 'group statement'`. From the output, DB::raw does indeed remove the backticks.

Comment: I've tried putting the entire sub-select SQL in the group by (which I've had to do in other situations) however because of the `SUM()` operation in the `select` MySQL rightly goes nuts.